# Utility for sending request signed X509 certificate

Tags: authentication, https, x509certificate, x509, utility

I have a server application which uses client certificate authentication. Each new user must get own certificate before he can use my application.

So, I want to use some utility to test user requests signed by x509 certificate. It can be any program or plugin for e.g. Chrome.

With best regards, Evgeniy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool like curl with the --cert argument (see http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) or wget with the --certificate argument (see http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options.html#HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options). Either or both are present on most *nix systems but the download locations are:

- curl: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
- wget: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm